# Can I add types to HSTORE in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

Does Postgres support any typed mapping that would support a datatype like this?

```
Mapping[string, date]
```

I know there's HSTORE and JSON, but as I understand neither are typed.

Comment: `HSTORE` values are always strings, `JSON` values are JSON values, date is not one of them. But depending on what you need, you can cast strings to timestamp either it a query, a stored procedure, or in the application code.